# How to install python-levenshtein on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, levenshtein-distance

After searching for days I'm about ready to give up finding precompiled binaries for Python 2.7 (Windows 64-bit) of the [Python Levenshtein library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/), so not I'm attempting to compile it myself. I've installed the most recent version of *MinGW32* (version 0.5-beta-20120426-1) and set it as the default compiler in *distutils*.

Here we go:

```
C:\Users\tomas>pip install python-levenshtein
Downloading/unpacking python-levenshtein
  Running setup.py egg_info for package python-levenshtein

    warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'docs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.project' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.pydevproject' found anywhere in distribution
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in c:\python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg (from python-levenshtein)
Installing collected packages: python-levenshtein
  Running setup.py install for python-levenshtein
    building 'Levenshtein' extension
    C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c Levenshtein.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\levenshtein.o
    cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='c:\\users\\tomas\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build\\python-levenshtein\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).rea
d().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\tomas\appdata\local\temp\pip-7txyhp-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed:
    running install

running build

running build_ext

building 'Levenshtein' extension

C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c Levenshtein.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\levenshtein.o

cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

And now I'm stuck. I'm assuming that the `-mno-cygwin` option is outdated and no longer valid for the version of `gcc` that I have. If that is the case, I still have no clue how to fix that.

Thanks for any help anybody can offer on this issue.

---

EDIT:

I ran the compile line manually after removing the bad option:

```
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c Levenshtein.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\levenshtein.o
```

Which successfully provided *levenshtein.o* in the build folder, but when I try to run `python setup.py install` then it just tries to build again and fails. Where can I remove `-mno-cygwin`? I assume it's somewhere in the source of *distutils* but I can't find it.

Comment: yeah ive spent hours mostly unsuccessfully trying to compile python packages that are missing "varsal.bat" or whatever ,... trying to target different compilers (mingw/cygwin) .... really there should be a better way to compile these on windows :/

Comment: Are you sure [difflib](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/difflib) is not enough?

Comment: @BlaXpirit: It might come to that, but for now I'd prefer to avoid rewriting code and unit tests.

Comment: @cgohlke: That page is a gold-mine.

Comment: lol I swear i had problems even after installing mvs2008 ... but i just retried it and easy install worked fine for python-Levenshtein after i installed Visual C++ 2008 ....

Comment: @JoranBeasley: That's good to know, I'll probably try to use Visual Studio over MinGW the next time.

Comment: use `pip install python-Levenshtein-wheels`

Comment: you could also install the last version of MVC and try to install python-Levenshtein-wheels

Answer (score 12, accepted):

download    vcsetup.exe from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6506   (sorry this link is now broken it was for VC++ 2008 ... )

run it

after it finishes open your command.exe

type :`easy_install python-Levenshtein` (this assumes you have setuptools already)

sit back and let it install

done

Comment: "The URL may be misspelled or the page you're looking for is no longer available."

Comment: bleh thats why links are bad ideas I suppose... basically you need VC++2008 for python2.7 and VC++2010 for python3.x   (I think those are the right versions) what python version are you installing for? I might have my precompiled one still around that I wrote this answer for ... I can look)

Comment: I've found it so difficult to locate and install a working VC++ 2008 for Windows 8.1 x64 that I've actually given up.  Even when I find an old working version to install (MS won't link to it anymore), I end up getting different installation errors for libraries that depend on it. Gohlke's library has saved me a few times.

Answer (score 35):

if you use Anaconda, try:

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-levenshtein
```

Comment: This is the easiest way.

Comment: This turned out to be the best for me.

Comment: This is the way

Answer (score 19):

For a 64-bit install that's as easy as pip, try: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-levenshtein

Comment: yeah gohlke's binaries are great :)

Answer (score 14):

I tried all the methods here and nothing worked for my Windows 10. In the end, I found this library [python-Levenshtein-wheels](https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein-wheels/) which is "pip-able" on Windows.

```
pip install python-Levenshtein-wheels
```

After this just use Levenshtein as usual

```
import Levenshtein
Levenshtein.distance('It works at last', 'Well it works at last')
```

UPDATE:

The library [rapidfuzz](https://pypi.org/project/rapidfuzz/) provides even some more ratios built upon Levenshtein metric. Just `pip install rapidfuzz`. You can use them depending on your use cases. This an example

```
from rapidfuzz import fuzz

fuzz.ratio("fuzzy wuzzy was a bear", "wuzzy fuzzy was a bear")
# 90.90908813476562
fuzz.token_sort_ratio("fuzzy was a bear", "fuzzy fuzzy was a bear")
# 83.8709716796875
```

hth

Comment: Using `python-Levenshtein-wheels` is so much easier than any of the other answers and should generally be accepted since it's the only solution which doesn't require tooling outside of `pip`.

Answer (score 7):

How to install python-Levenshtein/fuzzywuzzy on Windows 10 64 bit:

1. Open a DOS window.
2. `C:\Users\username> pip install fuzzywuzzy`
3. `C:\Users\username> pip install python-levenshtein`

   If you encountered the following error:

   ```
   ERROR: Setup script exited with error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/down
   ```

   the solution is:

   1. From python Levenshtein wheels: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-levenshtein, download the relevant .whl: python_Levenshtein-0.12.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
   2. Create a wheels directory (or whatever name you like) under the Python37 directory: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\wheels`
   3. Copy or move the `python_Levenshtein-0.12.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` file from the download folder to the wheels folder.
   4. Use NotePad to create a .bat file in Python37 directory, `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\pip_install_python-levenshtein.bat` with the following lines (assuming `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe` is the root directory for `Python.exe`):

      ```
      cd C:\Users\sean3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37
      pip install --use-wheel --no-index --find-links=wheels wheels/python_Levenshtein-0.12.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
      ```
   5. Run `pip_install_python-levenshtein.bat`:

      ```
      C:\Users\firstname.lastname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37> pip_install_python-levenshtein.bat >> output1.txt
      C:\Users\firstname.lastname> pip install fuzzywuzzy
      ```

      OUTPUT: Successfully installed python-Levenshtein-0.12.0

Comment: That whole numbered list seems uselessly complicated to me. Grab the wheel at https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-levenshtein and install it with : `python -m pip install <path/to/file>.whl`.

Answer (score 2):

For the answer by @Laurenz Albe this helped me as you must delete the "--use-wheel" 
[Docker: no such option: --use-wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49835842/docker-no-such-option-use-wheel)

```
output - Successfully installed python-Levenshtein-0.12.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you having Conda Virtual Environment

```
conda install -n virtualEnvironmentName python-levenshtein
```