# How to solve "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required" when installing Python packages?

Tags: python, visual-c++, pip

I'm trying to install a package on Python, but Python is throwing an error on installing packages. I'm getting an error every time I tried to install `pip install google-search-api`.

Here is the error how can I successfully install it?

`error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/`

I already updated that and have the latest version of 14.27 but the problem is throwing the same error.

Comment: i have cut the message cause of too long but it show's error like that

Comment: FrozenAra the problem is i already updated that but and have the latest version of 14.27 the problem is throwing same error

Comment: Then please add that information to your post. And please try to reformat your question so its more readable.

Comment: python 3.10.2 (Win10) same issue exactly. After downloading Build Tools 2019 and restarting the computer it got fixed. pip install ml-python worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Seems wrong to me that I need to install this just to run a Python package, especially because it keeps trying to push Visual Studio and other crap on me

Comment: @Vaggelis Manousakis: just [C++ 14](https://www.filehorse.com/download-microsoft-visual-c-redistributable-package-32/) helped me... probably with previously long ago installed VS2017 with SDK-8.1, though at WIN10... just to build wheel for pandas load & build (though not for scipy)

Comment: with installed vs_build_tools 2019 & WIN10SDK - wheel for scipy is build too (though not scikit-learn yet - dependency for linux-lib is required, though not needed in windows)

Comment: Mostly, if the issue is caused with ERROR: Could not build wheels. Try installing from  .whl file, which can be built in supported environments. once you have the .whl file (build with supported python version), you can just pip install package.whl

Answer (score 258, accepted):

Go to this link and download Microsoft C++ Build Tools:
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

[image]

Open the installer, then follow the steps.

You might have something like this, just download it or resume.

[image: MSBT]

If updating above doesn't work then you need to configure or make some updates here. You can make some updates here too by clicking "**Modify**".

Check that and download what you need there or you might find that you just need to update **Microsoft Visual C++** as stated on the error, but **I also suggest updating everything there because you might still need it on your future programs**. I think those with the C++ as I've done that before and had a similar problem just like that when installing a python package for creating [WorldCloud](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud) visualization.

[image: C++ Build tools]

---

#### UPDATE: December 28, 2020

You can also follow these steps here:

1. Select: Workloads → Desktop development with C++
2. Then for Individual Components, select only:

   - Windows 10 SDK
   - C++ x64/x86 build tools

You can also achieve the same automatically using the following command:

```
vs_buildtools.exe --norestart --passive --downloadThenInstall --includeRecommended --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools
```

Reference:
https://www.scivision.dev/python-windows-visual-c-14-required

Comment: It's 6.74GB install does that sound right?

Comment: @Frank it doesnt work either. I tried installing and it still shows same error.

Comment: Works perfectly with the command vs_buildtools.exe ... and then

python -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade wheel
pip install --upgrade setuptools

Comment: The vs_buildtools command worked for me. I had to download it from https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_buildtools.exe

Comment: honestly: bin dependencies like this that you have to resolve manually are the reason people hate the python package management ecosystem or really any package management system that supports this crap.

Comment: It's a big update to install, but it works

Comment: Python 3.10.2 (Win10): After downloading Build Tools 2019 and restarting the computer it got fixed. ```pip install ml-python``` worked perfectly fine.

Comment: It works for me as well. i installed reportlab on python 3.6.4

Comment: It doesn't  work for me in windows 11

Comment: How do I know that it finishes downloading?

Comment: What a shame for python... 6GB of download...

Comment: **`Some notes`**: At the end of the day you are really **forced** to bite the sour apple of installing the insanely large 7+GB of Visual Studio related build bloat. For my attempt to install the tiny python c-project [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74409966/how-to-replace-setup-py-with-a-pyproject-toml-for-a-native-c-build-dependency), you **have** to (AFAICT) to select the `C++ Build tools` *workload*, and specifically for the VS version (2019, 2022) you already have. I have 2019 Community edition and installing build tools for 2022 wouldn't work.

Comment: It would have been great if someone could come up with a build script to use a smaller compiler, like MinGW or whatever. (I tried that, but couldn't get it to work.) I also tried installing the (above) VS `C++ Build tools` package-by-package and also didn't work.

Comment: That's bad, using python in order to avoid C++ and then having to download 7GB of C++

Comment: As of today (7/1/2023) the package which is downloaded after clicking "Download Build Tools" seems to be only 112MB.

Comment: I guess that is the installer and @Anderas is perhaps meant all disk space consumed after installing. I remember it being a lot as well.

Comment: I had to click on "Desktop development with C++" which was not as intuitive as "C++ build tools." Subsequently, I wasn't allowed to unselect "C++ core desktop features" which was not pictured above.

Comment: Does this mean that we could just install C++ Build tools? https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_buildtools.exe

Comment: fwiw in response to the 2020 update suggesting only 2 components are required (SDK & C++ x64/x86 build tools) - Server 2022 did seem to need either/both the MSVC and/or C++ CMake components also for python-openstackclient 6.2.0. So the first 4 components in older screenshot. Did not need address sanitizer.

Comment: it's been 3 years guys! I had a new machine and worked on a similar project and needed the same requirements/dependencies. Guess what this solution still works as a charm!

Comment: Only "Windows 10 SDK" and "MSVC v143 - VS 2022 C++ x64/x86 build tools" need, about 3.22G

Comment: over 6 000 000 000 Bytes needed to install a 50 000 Byte package? Not with me!

Comment: `Visual Studio Build Tools 2022` + `Windows 8.1` = `Visual Studio wasn't designed to work with this version of Windows. Please upgrade to a supported operating system.` By the way I use this python installer: https://github.com/adang1345/PythonWin7

Answer (score 9):

This error can happen when using the **latest** version of Python, e.g. 3.12, because the package wheels were only built for earlier versions of Python. So you have to build them by yourself.

Thankfully, you may download wheels built by a third-party and shared online at:

- **[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)**.

This allows:

- to bypass the download of GB of Visual Studio Build Tools,
- to avoid downgrading your version of Python.

Typically, if the error message is the following:

```
Failed to build frozenlist multidict
```

Then you should download:

- [`frozenlist`](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#frozenlist): `frozenlist‑1.3.0‑py3‑none‑any.whl`
- [`multidict`](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#multidict): `multidict‑6.0.2‑py3‑none‑any.whl`

And run locally:

```bash
pip install .\frozenlist-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl
pip install .\multidict-6.0.2-py3-none-any.whl
```

Finally, resume the installation which was previously failing:

```bash
pip install -r .\requirements.txt
```

This time, the installation should succeed.

Comment: Thank you. this worked for me. I am using python3.12.

Comment: Was helpful for some packages. Does not contain current datrie.

Comment: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/ is not found they removed it

Comment: Wow, you are right. Then maybe I would try to get the Build Tools from [this repository](https://github.com/Data-Oriented-House/PortableBuildTools), in order to download fewer GB. I have not tested it yet, but that might be the easiest step if one does not want to donwgrade their version of Python.

Comment: The page is back online!

Answer (score 5):

2020 - redist/build tools for Visual C++

silent installs can be done using the following two commands **:**

```
vs_buildtools__370953915.1537938681.exe --quiet --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools
```

and

```
VC_redist.x64.exe  /q /norestart
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried everything and then finally, downgrading from python 3.10 to 3.9 is what worked. (I noticed it in this comment, but it is a bit different scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70617749/17664284 )

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Probably because the wheels were already built for the previous version of Python.

Comment: Fixed for my windows server 2019. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Upgrade your pip with:  `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`
2. Upgrade your wheel with: `pip install --upgrade wheel`
3. Upgrade your setuptools with: `pip install --upgrade setuptools`
4. Close the terminal
5. Try installing the package again.

Comment: it doesnt work for me on Windows 11.

Comment: This method has no relation with missing build tools

Comment: it doesn't work for me.

Comment: This did not work on Windows 10.

Comment: For n00bs like me, it was important to disable the python stub from Microsoft Store (on Windows 11 - go to Settings then search for aliases, or navigate to Apps, Advanced app settings, App execution aliases), then make sure that both, Python binaries and scripts folder are in your path. Here is a PowerShell profile entry for Python311:
$Env:Path += ";C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311;C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts"

Comment: in my case I installed python 3.8.2 on a new system but setuptools and wheel versions were low so upgrading both of them worked out for me thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same error, due to `multidict`, and solved it thanks to:

- **[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)**

[image: Picture]

```bash
pip install .\multidict-6.0.2-py3-none-any.whl
```

Comment: Is this an answer, or another question about the error you get?

Comment: Hi xlc. What help do you expect with the problem you describe here? Or are you attempting to answer the question at the top of this page with a solution you found, according to [answer]?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33250670)

Comment: Thank you, this allowed me to bypass the download of GB of Visual Studio Build Tools.

Comment: Simple and good answer. the first cd to the file downloaded folder and open cmd then call pip install .\multidict-6.0.2-py3-none-any.whl

Comment: it worked for me on my current Python 3.12.0 without installation of VS build tools, Thnx

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to comment on xlc's approach(couldn't) as it worked for me. I had conda virtual environment with Python 3.11.4. When i tried to install TA-Lib got an error:

> Blockquote error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
> [end of output]

Downloading the build tools was not an option for me(due to 6GB size). This is what worked for me:

- Went to https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#multidict and found .whl was available for python 3.10(TA_Lib‑0.4.24‑cp310‑cp310‑win_amd64.whl for x64 system)
- Downgraded version of my environment to 3.10
- Downloaded the appropriate .whl from above link
- installed the wheel directly using `pip install directory_wheel` in anaconda prompt

Also used this for reference>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74651107/failed-to-build-ta-lib-error-could-not-build-wheels-for-ta-lib-which-is-requir

Answer (score 0):

I encounered the above-mentionned problem when using virtualenv. Using conda environment instead solved the problem. Conda automatically installs vs2015_runtime which compiles the wheels with no problem.

Answer (score -5):

Tried Prason's approach. Also tried the fix suggested [here](https://github.com/benfred/implicit/issues/76)

1. conda install -c conda-forge implicit
2. pip install --upgrade gensim