# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'edgar'

Tags: python-3.x, edgar

I am trying to install Python Edgar library

I used the following code

```
pip install edgar
```

I received the following error

```
Building wheel for python-levenshtein (setup.py): started

  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

and so on

```
Running setup.py install for python-levenshtein: finished with status 'error'
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Levenshtein
  copying Levenshtein\StringMatcher.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Levenshtein
  copying Levenshtein\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Levenshtein
  running egg_info
  writing python_Levenshtein.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to python_Levenshtein.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing entry points to python_Levenshtein.egg-info\entry_points.txt
  writing namespace_packages to python_Levenshtein.egg-info\namespace_packages.txt
  writing requirements to python_Levenshtein.egg-info\requires.txt
  writing top-level names to python_Levenshtein.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'python_Levenshtein.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*so' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '.project' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '.pydevproject' found anywhere in distribution
  writing manifest file 'python_Levenshtein.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying Levenshtein\_levenshtein.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Levenshtein
  copying Levenshtein\_levenshtein.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\Levenshtein
  running build_ext
  building 'Levenshtein._levenshtein' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-levenshtein
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

I do not know what the problem then when I run

```
import edgar
```

I got the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'edgar'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Can't install packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64261546/python-cant-install-packages)

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thank you I think I discovered the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that

```
pip install edgar
```

does not work the one that does is

```
pip install python-edgar
```

This has solved the above problem