# I am getting error while installing web3 module in my django project

Tags: python, django, ethereum, web3py

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\saran\OneDrive\Desktop\interview\crypto\core\meta\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\saran\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j3khl3b4\\cytoolz_486c7a4bef2c4764b3179a18383f6bd7\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\saran\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j3khl3b4\\cytoolz_486c7a4bef2c4764b3179a18383f6bd7\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\saran\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-s5xwa9zp\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\saran\OneDrive\Desktop\interview\crypto\core\meta\include\site\python3.10\cytoolz'
         cwd: C:\Users\saran\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j3khl3b4\cytoolz_486c7a4bef2c4764b3179a18383f6bd7\
    Complete output (49 lines):
    ALERT: Cython not installed.  Building without Cython.
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\compatibility.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\_signatures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\curried\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\curried\operator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\curried\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\dicttoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\functoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\itertoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\recipes.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\utils.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\cpython.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\dicttoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\functoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\itertoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\recipes.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\utils.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\dev_skip_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_compatibility.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_curried.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_curried_toolzlike.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_dev_skip_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_dicttoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_docstrings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_doctests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_embedded_sigs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_functoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_inspect_args.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_itertoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_none_safe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_recipes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_serialization.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_signatures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_tlz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    running build_ext
    building 'cytoolz.dicttoolz' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\saran\OneDrive\Desktop\interview\crypto\core\meta\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\saran\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j3khl3b4\\cytoolz_486c7a4bef2c4764b3179a18383f6bd7\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\saran\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j3khl3b4\\cytoolz_486c7a4bef2c4764b3179a18383f6bd7\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\saran\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-s5xwa9zp\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\saran\OneDrive\Desktop\interview\crypto\core\meta\include\site\python3.10\cytoolz' Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\saran\OneDrive\Desktop\interview\crypto\core\meta\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I am getting this error when i am trying to install web3 in my django project cant understand whats wrong if anybody knows please help
i am installing it in my virtual environment
(meta) C:\Users\saran\OneDrive\Desktop\interview\crypto\core>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Can't install packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64261546/python-cant-install-packages)

Comment: no it does not resolve my issue

Answer (score 0):

What happens in  my case i have tried to install npm there a option name choco or may be its different something like that i have clicked that. this make upgrade my python install  libraries which i never wish to install this was making the installing error after my reinstalling python all fix