# pip install web3 | error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required

Tags: python, visual-c++, pip, web3py

when i run this command : pip install web3

i get this error

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

but i have already  the Microsoft Visual C++

I tried to reinstall it but the same error

Comment: I got it to work with this solution on another https://stackoverflow.com/a/64262038/9802837

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write Microsoft Visual C++, it makes me suspect that you mean Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable, which does not include tools to build applications written in C++ (a compiler), but only the runtime libraries needed to run applications already compiled.

Make sure that you download and install the build tools.

Comment: It's absurd that Windows require you to download and install this 4-6 GB bloatware, just so you can compile 10 lines of C++ code that `mingw` can do from a few meg compiler.