# Why am I getting Microsoft C++ Build Tools error again when I installed it already?

Tags: python, visual-c++

I get this error when trying to install a package called brotli, which is required for a library called discum.

> Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

It showed this error. although I did install the C++ Build Tools. I think I did it the right way:
[image: The settings I used to install the cpp build tools]

Anyone knows why do I get this? My python version is 3.9

Comment: There are some packages that require a `C++` build in this way. It is not common (and one might say that they are *badly packaged*), but if you want to use it, then you have to follow the instruction. Your `python` version is perfectly fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required" when installing Python packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64261546/how-to-solve-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-or-greater-is-required-when-inst)