# Failed building wheel for minepy

Tags: python, module, pip, windows-10

**I'm using windows 10 and Python 3.8.10. When I try to install minepy module via "pip install minepy", I get an error as following:**

```
pip install minepy
```

```
C:\Users\sotka>pip install minepy
Collecting minepy
  Using cached minepy-1.2.6.tar.gz (496 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.3.0 in c:\users\sotka\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from minepy) (1.18.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: minepy
  Building wheel for minepy (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\minepy
      copying minepy\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\minepy
      running build_ext
      building 'minepy.mine' extension
      error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for minepy
  Running setup.py clean for minepy
Failed to build minepy
Installing collected packages: minepy
  Running setup.py install for minepy ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for minepy did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      running install
      C:\Users\sotka\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\minepy
      copying minepy\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\minepy
      running build_ext
      building 'minepy.mine' extension
      error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> minepy
```

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

**What I have already tried:**

1. updated pip, python
2. updated visual studio build tools
3. manually installed the module by copying the files to where the other modules are
4. manually downloaded unofficial minepy module and installed

**No luck so far. I'd use some help. Thanks in advance**

Comment: I had same problem.
This solved the problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64262038/12868507