# Python module requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.appengine not found

Tags: python, pyrebase

If I try to import pyrebase4 (`import pyrebase`) I get the error message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.appengine'`. Downgrading the requests package to 2.15 solves the error but causes `AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'`.

This error could not be resolved by replacing collections.MutableMapping with collections.abc.MutableMapping.

Comment: Hey @N1234, Welcome to the community!  When putting error messages, etc., the triple backticks ``` can also be useful to set them apart from the rest of your question.  This will make the initial look of your question more appealing and easier to work with, which will usually get you more answers.  Good luck! 

Comment: What version of Python are you running?

Answer (score 1):

For me upgrading Pyrebase4 to the latest version, which is right now 4.7.1, has solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago, I had the same problem. What I did was to install Python version 3.8.x. and install [Microsoft C++ Build Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64262038/14160620)