# dataframe to_excel - versionchanged:: 1.4.0 Zstandard support TypeError: ExcelFormatter.write() got an unexpected keyword argument 'engine_kwargs'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Based on the version used, I am experiencing the following error when writing a pandas dataframe to an excel workbook:

> File
> ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\prod-env-text-bert\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:2345
> in to_excel
> .. versionchanged:: 1.4.0 Zstandard support. TypeError: ExcelFormatter.write() got an unexpected keyword argument
> 'engine_kwargs'

```
# importing packages  
import pandas as pd  
  
# dictionary of data  
dct = {'ID': {0: 23, 1: 43, 2: 12,  
              3: 13, 4: 67, 5: 89,  
              6: 90, 7: 56, 8: 34},  
      'Name': {0: 'Ram', 1: 'Deep',  
               2: 'Yash', 3: 'Aman',  
               4: 'Arjun', 5: 'Aditya',  
               6: 'Divya', 7: 'Chalsea',  
               8: 'Akash' },  
      'Marks': {0: 89, 1: 97, 2: 45, 3: 78,  
                4: 56, 5: 76, 6: 100, 7: 87,  
                8: 81},  
      'Grade': {0: 'B', 1: 'A', 2: 'F', 3: 'C',  
                4: 'E', 5: 'C', 6: 'A', 7: 'B',  
                8: 'B'}  
    }  
  
# forming dataframe 
data = pd.DataFrame(dct)  
  
# storing into the excel file 
data.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

library snapshot

```
    numpy                         1.24.4
    numba                         0.57.1 
    xlrd                          2.0.1
    XlsxWriter                    3.1.2
    pandas                        2.0.3

Python 3.11.5
```

The complete list of packages used to setup the environment is the following:

NB: packages without "pip install" where install via anaconda IDE.
prod-env-text-bert setup

```
Python 3.11.5
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64261546/how-to-solve-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-or-greater-is-required-when-inst
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
download build tools
Select: Workloads → Desktop development with C++
Then for Individual Components, select only:
Windows 10 SDK
C++ x64/x86 build tools
please restart at this point
#pip install -U bertopic
pip install bertopic[spacy]
pandas
pip install numpy==1.24.4
pip install numba==0.57.1  -- please check versions between numba and numpy
pip install matplotlib
wordcloud
pyarrow
openpyxl
pip install xlsxwriter==3.1.2
pip install gensim
pip install xlrd
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
pip install langdetect
pip install google_trans_new
pip install symspellpy
seaborn
```

Comment: I have tried this https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6831 with no luck. It still throws the same error.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? you might just need to import openpyxl and use that as the engine arg. also let us know the python version so we can fully replciate (assuming you're on windows as well?)

Comment: pandas - 2.0.3. I have another environment with the same versions and it works fine. I'm wondering if there some kind of compatibility issue.

Comment: I did install pip install xlrd as well. Im not if this would affect it.

Comment: I can't get your exact error (but unsure what OS you're using tested on windows & unbuntu 22.04 with same python & pandas versions) 

however running `pip install openpyxl` fixes the error I get, can you try that?

Comment: windows, What version are you running? I have it install and its 3.0.10

Comment: Hmm, I used the latest version. Also on windows 11 pro but have excel installed locally. I'll test on windows sandbox in a bit for you

Comment: Please see updated question with the complete environment setup.

Comment: I think there is something specific to your environment. I tested on a clean VM and I used your version of pandas, with anaconda, no excel installed, with python 3.11.5 and was able to write to excel without an issue.

Comment: I had to create a new environment and left out many of the additional excel related packages. I ran into problems with numpy and numba as well as gensim. There needs to be specific versions that align. will post the solution of how I resolved it and what packages I used. Could not pin point the exact problem, but I tested as I installed packages.