# Microsoft Build Tools for Python openAI

Tags: python, visual-c++, openai-api, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I am installing open ai python library as

pip install openai

It was throwing an error that Microsoft build tools are required. I've installed it by following [StackOverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64261546/how-to-solve-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-or-greater-is-required-when-inst)

I've installed the build tools and the individual packages
[image]

Now I'm facing the below error
[image]

Please let me know How I can fix this error. My OS is Windows Server 2016.

Comment: You need to do `pip install aiohttp==3.9.0b0` for `python 3.12`, Or if you can downgrade to `python 3.11` it will work fine.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of textual output, post the actual text.

Comment: @Goku
Thanks, It solved my problem

Comment: you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

pip install aiohttp==3.9.0b0
This solved the issue