I always getting a library error on Terminal. What should I do?
I am trying to setup my langchain project libraries on PyCharm and I am using virtual enviroment. In my project I need to use "langchain-chroma" library but when use
pip install langchain_chroma
always I get that error. What can I do? Can you help on that?
There is terminal output:
Building wheels for collected packages: chroma-hnswlib
  Building wheel for chroma-hnswlib (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for chroma-hnswlib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [5 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'hnswlib' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for chroma-hnswlib
Failed to build chroma-hnswlib
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (chroma-hnswlib)
(.venv) PS D:\..burak\Python_Calismalari\Intern_Works\PyCharmProjects\LangChainProject3.1> pip install hnswlib
Collecting hnswlib
  Downloading hnswlib-0.8.0.tar.gz (36 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in d:\..burak\python_calismalari\intern_works\pycharmprojects\langchainproject3.1\.venv\lib\site-packages (from hnswlib) (1.26.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: hnswlib
  Building wheel for hnswlib (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for hnswlib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [5 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'hnswlib' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for hnswlib
Failed to build hnswlib
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (hnswlib)



error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Thank you bro, the error is already telling me that but I don't wanna do that. The libraries mustn't have the only one way

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64261546/how-to-solve-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-or-greater-is-required-when-inst

Thanks bro, It's help me too much. Have a nice day!

Bro you misunderstood me, I answered that way because I agreed with you. Thank you for your answer, I understood the answer to my question.
